# "docker run --memory" doesn't account hugepages

Tags: docker, huge-pages

Docker is running in privileged mode.
I want to know if this behavior is expected.

I am running DPDK based application in container.
My server has total 128G memory, I have limited container memory resource to 4G.
which I can see in docker stats.

```
CONTAINER ID        NAME                     CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS                       [0/18152]
4deda4634b22        my_docker                38.12%              1.455GiB / 4GiB       36.37%              1.53kB / 0B         1.94GB / 755MB      69
```

I am seeing that even after docker memory is constraint to 4G.
application is able to allocate 32G huge pages memory along with other non huge page memory.
Is it expected?
Does `docker run --memory` option work only with non-huge page memory?

```
root@server# docker exec -ti my_docker bash
root@4deda4634b22:/#
root@4deda4634b22:/# ps aux |grep riot
root       893 17.2  0.0 68345740 105260 pts/0 Sl   05:54   1:02 /app/riot   <<<<<< application.


root@4deda4634b22:/# cat /proc/meminfo |grep -i huge
AnonHugePages:    909312 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
**HugePages_Total:      32**
**HugePages_Free:        0**  
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:    1048576 kB

root@4deda4634b22:/# ls -rlt /mnt/huge/*  | wc -l
32
```

Comment: I am not able to find the execution of the program in `DOCKER` which used 32G of huge page. Can you confirm before starting docket, 32G huge page is already used or not?

Answer (score 0):

I normally pass the access for huge page and vfio devices via `docker run -it --privileged -v /sys/bus/pci/drivers:/sys/bus/pci/drivers -v /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages:/sys/kernel/mm/hugepages -v /sys/devices/system/node:/sys/devices/system/node -v /dev:/dev`.

It looks like you are missing the same.

Comment: Thanks Vipin, How many hugepages do you see in that case inside docker? Does your application failed to allocate hugepages if application alloc more than provisioned memory?

Comment: I ran my DPDK applciation with `--socket-limit=8192,1` this allowed me to use 8GB of huge page. But as mentioned  in comment, I am unable to find your application or allocation for 32GB.

Comment: Thanks Vipin, if you dont specify --socket-mem or --socket-limit then dpdk application would try to consume all huge pages. In your case try giving socket-limit which is equal to total huge pages available in your system. That is what is happening for me. it means "docker --memory" is not applicable to huge pages as such.

Comment: DPDK application also uses memory and heap area, hence it requires normal memory too. For any docker environment, you should allow access to huge pages and mounting area. hopefully, you can get access via the answer shared.

Comment: @AshishGupta if the answer has solved the issue, please upvote and accept the answer