# "docker run --memory": How internal applications can know about docker memory provisioning?

Tags: docker

I am running docker in privileged mode.
Docker is running DPDK based application.
My server has total 128G memory, I have limited container memory resource to 4G.
which I can see in docker stats.

```
            CONTAINER ID        NAME                     CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS                       [0/18152]
            4deda4634b22        my_docker                38.12%              1.455GiB / 4GiB       36.37%              1.53kB / 0B         1.94GB / 755MB      69
```

I see full 128G memory inside docker.

My applications, read host available memory and based on that individual application allocate a
portion of total memory.
eg. I hv two applications inside docker. if total available memory inside docker is 6G.
each application will work with 3G memory.
if docker total memory is constraint to 4G.
each application suppose to work with 2G.
This scheme of allocation will not work in docker as it sees all host memory.
Is there any workaround?

```
root@4deda4634b22:/# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
              Mem:         128961       35277       75558        2051       18125       90019
              Swap:        131037           5      131032
root@4deda4634b22:/#
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["docker run --memory" doesn't account hugepages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62149553/docker-run-memory-doesnt-account-hugepages)

Comment: Hi Ashish, this is similar tohttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/62149553/docker-run-memory-doesnt-account-hugepages?r=Search results. As explained, you can limit amount memory used by a docker, but when you use DPDK, it pulls.the huge pages from reserved memory and not 4K page memory. So if you need 2 dpdk application running in docker use 'file-prefix' and 'socket-limit'. But if your concern is amount 'free -' this is not a dpdk library issue

Comment: Hi Vipin, other thread has question related to huge page, consider I have limited docker to use 4G memory. In case of Huge page even if I use socket-limit, I am sure I would be able to give more then 4G to my process say socket-mem “--socket-mem 8192” Internally dpdk will use huge pages and allocation would succeeded. 
contrary, if we alloc from non-huge page, docker won’t allow to run that process if its allocating more than 4G.

Comment: - Current thread, has different question.
my another application is not dpdk based, it actually queries total available memory in system and allocate half of total memory for consumption.
that application will see full host memory (128G) and try to work with 64G (rlimit is unlimited).
Now docker is spawn with --memory 4G, that way my application would not be allowed to run.

Comment: Hi Ashish, then your question `I want to make use of standard memory (4K) pages in docker with is limited by 4GB. I would like to assign half the assigned memory rather than the system memory. How can I accomplish this?`. My suggestion is look into `docker stats for user-specific instance to get the memory rather than fetching host total memory`

Comment: Thanks Vipin.
Yeah, that is what required. Can we see docker stats from application running inside docker ?

Comment: Ashish I am not an expert on docker, hence my suggestion is try using `docker stats` from HOST, set the desired value into docker as environment variable. Another way is making use of groups for memory. But accessing something inside docker is tricky as you will need binary and support inside docker (making it complicated)

Comment: As workaround i am doing that but i had to change my application to fetch env variable along with checking total memory. I was looking for solution where i don't need to modify app. Thanks Vipin, looks like that is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default each docker container can use all resources available by the host. If you want to restrict a container to a certain amount of memory you have to specify that explicitly with the `--memory` option as explained by the docker [docs on resource constraints](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/).

Example (4gb limit): `docker run --memory 4096m your_container_name`

Note that you will see the whole memory of your system with `free -m`. However you can check the memory limit from within the container in this file: `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.limit_in_bytes`

Example to verify this quickly: `docker run --rm --memory 4096m debian cat sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.limit_in_bytes`

If you add such a memory limit you have to make sure that your application will adhere to that limit. If it tries to use more memory than that limit, it will be killed.

Also note that if you don't set the `--memory-swap` limit your application can use the memory you've defined + the same amount of swap. (In this case the application could use 4gb of ram and an additional 4gb of the swap) If you don't your application to use any swap you should set the memory and memory-swap limit to the same amount.

(The memory-swap value is the ram + swap your application can use and should therefore by alwayws >= than the memory limit.)

Example: `docker run --memory 4096m --memory-swap 4096m your_container_name`

Comment: Thanks was looking for this info.

Comment: @AshishGupta Do you mind accepting the answer if it was what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks Leo. Yes, your answer solves my purpose. 
Accepted as answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's explained very well here: https://fabianlee.org/2020/01/18/docker-placing-limits-on-container-memory-using-cgroups/

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing the question and answer based on the discussion so far as

question: `I want to run 2 non-DPDK application in a docker environment with 4GB total reserved (4K pages). Inside docker bash I get total system memory and not the docker reserved memory. Is there an API or binary which can be used inside docker bash to get the right reserved memory?`

answer: My suggestion is to look into docker stats for user-specific instance to get the memory rather than fetching host total memory. hence my suggestion is to try using docker stats from HOST, set the desired value into docker as an environment variable. Another way is making use of groups for memory. But accessing something inside docker is tricky as you will need binary and support inside docker (making it complicated)